# Multi-Base Primes

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, primes, integer

For the purpose of this challenge, a multi-base prime is a prime which, when written in base 10, is prime in one or more bases smaller than 10 and larger than 1 as well.  All single-digit primes are trivially multi-base primes.  11 is also a multi-base prime, as 11 in binary is 3, which is prime (it is also prime in base 4 and base 6).  The first few terms are: 2,3,5,7,11,13, 17, 23,31,37,41,43,47,53,61...

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that, when given an integer as input, returns/outputs a truthy value if the input is a multi-base prime, and a falsy value if it is not.

### Input:

An integer between 1 and 10^12.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy valule, depending on whether the input is a multi-base prime.

### Test Cases:

```
3    -> truthy
4    -> falsy
13   -> truthy
2003 -> truthy (Also prime in base 4)
1037 -> falsy (2017 in base 5 but not a prime in base 10)
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: Could you add a test case that's prime in base-2 and base-10 only? I haven't been able to find any such numbers yet but if any *do* exist, I'll need to update my solution.

Comment: @Shaggy  `173,1259,1277,2069,2099,2237,2797,2801,3331,3539,3541,3851,3929,3989,4261,4349,4373,5077,5087,5279,5399,6047,6269,6389...`

Comment: Thanks, @StraklSeth. I'd since found a couple but my solution needed to be updated anyway.

Comment: Isn't 17 a multi-base prime as well (`101` in base 4)?

Comment: I concur that 17 seems to be a prime in bases 4, 6, and 10.

Comment: The binary evaluation of `19` would be eleven (**2^1×1+2^0×9=11**), so it seems we are to explicitly ignore evaluating those possibilities that include "excessive digits" - is this correct?

Comment: I nominated this question for reopening but I now realize it is unclear.  I would like to see the "excessive digit" problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>159</s> 137 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:p(n)*any(p(b(n,i))for i in range(2,10))
p=lambda n:all(n%x for x in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1))
b=lambda n,i:n and n%i+10*b(n/i,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETv/Yq9CLtR2kRbBKEfE7G2C3YM4kG/Pk2h1Nxmhnm8sK@vGXWM433y737whC4wxHjsHLhnVCoyzgspKWjxeD64rpwVOYUD8dPEKDb6Hrf8qFgZxtjzTUqXmP7PVNqBPAZCoaWzJqkummQxLAmikZtk@MXrEV0219ZmzdmmzVrbSPwA)

Saved 22 bytes thanks to ovs.

Comment: [137 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETv/Yq9CLtR2kRbBKEfE7G2C3YM4kG/Pk2h1Nxmhnm8sK@vGXWM433y737whC4wxHjsHLhnVCoyzgspKWjxeD64rpwVOYUD8dPEKDb6Hrf8qFgZxtjzTUqXmP7PVNqBPAZCoaWzJqkummQxLAmikZtk@MXrEV0219ZmzdmmzVrbSPwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
Or@@(p=PrimeQ)[FromDigits/@IntegerDigits[#,2~Range~9]]&&p@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n27737/IwUGjwDagKDM3NVAz2q0oP9clMz2zpFjfwTOvJDU9tQjCjVbWMaoLSsxLT62zjI1VUytwUFb7D9SVV6LgkB5taGBsHvv/PwA)

Comment: As it stands `19` should be falsey even though `1,9` in "binary" is `1*2+9=11` which is prime. Edit - I've posted a comment under the OP to ask about this.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't really get you...19 in binary is 10011...

Comment: The question poses it the other way around: "11 is also a multi-base prime, as 11 in binary is 3, which is prime"

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
j ©Ao2@sX nÃdj
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=aiCpQW8yQHNYIG7DZGo=&input=MjAwMw==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
j
```

Test if input is prime (Boo-urns to input validation!).

```
©
```

Logical AND (`&&`).

```
Ao2@    Ã
```

Generate an array of integers from `2` to `9` and pass each through a function where `X` is the current element.

```
sX n
```

Convert `U` to a base-`X` string (`s`) and back to an integer (`n`).

```
dj
```

Check if any of the numbers in the array are prime.